# swift start music after user phone call

Tags: ios, swift, background-music

I am not quite sure if I am missing a function or something, but when a users phone rings and or they ask siri or anything that stops my app audio from playing. It does not re-start my app playing when the user has finished their task.

I am wondering is there a function I am missing, or can Apple iOS apps not do this?

I thought it would be something to do with:

```
func setupRemoteTransportControls() {
   // Get the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    // Add handler for Play Command
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
        if self.player?.rate == 0.0 {
            self.player?.play()
            return .success
        }
        return .commandFailed
    }

    // Add handler for Pause Command
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
        if self.player?.rate == 1.0 {
            self.player?.pause()
            return .success
        }
        return .commandFailed
    }

   // self.nowplaying(artist: "Anna", song: "test")


}
```

I have found that I need to add this part but how do I call it?

```
func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {

        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let interruptionTypeRawValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
            let interruptionType = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: interruptionTypeRawValue) else {
            return
        }

        switch interruptionType {
        case .began:
            print("interruption began")
        case .ended:
            print("interruption ended")
        default:
            print("UNKNOWN")
        }

    }
```

Comment: How is your av session configured?

Comment: We don't have AVSession at the moment - I only found that this is needed. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH4-SW5

Not sure if that goes into my viewController though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your audio session to [`AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosessioncategoryplayback).  If you don't set this mode, you will have the default mode [`AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/category/1616488-soloambient).

You can set the mode in `didFinishLaunching`.

e.g.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    // Get the singleton instance.
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        // Set the audio session category, mode, and options.
        try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [])
    } catch {
        print("Failed to set audio session category.")
    }
    
    // Other post-launch configuration.
    return true
}
```

You will also need to implement [interruption observation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_interruptions)

```
func setupNotifications() {
    // Get the default notification center instance.
    let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.addObserver(self,
                   selector: #selector(handleInterruption),
                   name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification,
                   object: nil)
}

@objc func handleInterruption(notification: Notification) {
    // To be implemented.
}
```

Comment: So I added that, I don't see anything that tells me if the session was interupted.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_interruptions